# When could ShellExecute fail? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I am planning to use ShellExecute for the updater of an application written in delphi 2007, I was wondering if ShellExecute will work on most computers with Win or if it can easly fail because of some user permission or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx)

> **Remarks**
>
> Because ShellExecute can delegate
>   execution to Shell extensions (data
>   sources, context menu handlers, verb
>   implementations) that are activated
>   using Component Object Model (COM),
>   COM should be initialized before
>   ShellExecute is called. Some Shell
>   extensions require the COM
>   single-threaded apartment (STA) type.
>   In that case, COM should be
>   initialized as shown here:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)
```

And as Ken Lange alread suggested, deppending on what you want to execute, you may need administrative rights.

Comment: Even so, the use that Sebastian intends should not require COM at all. In fact, it doesn't require ShellExecute. CreateProcess is a much better function for executing a known program, such as the updating program.

Answer (score 1):

I believe shellExecute does require admin. You didn't mention the OS. If it is Vista+ then UAC comes in to play. see [this explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)

Comment: You believe incorrectly. ShellExecute does not require administrative privileges in and of itself. (Think about it: Double-clicking a document in Explorer doesn't require elevated privileges, and ShellExecute is exactly what gets called in that situation.)